# How to use the deep-deep project?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Enlace del proyecto:**

https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/deep-deep

**I have created a .SH file to install all its dependencies:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Instalando proyecto deep-deep IA"
apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.5/Python-3.5.5.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.5.5.tgz
cd Python-3.5.5
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install pytest
apt-get install pytest-twisted
pip install pytest-twisted
python3 -m pip install -U git+git://github.com/python/mypy.git
apt install tox
git clone https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/deep-deep.git
cd deep-deep/
tox
```

**after installation I have installed run examples / standalone.py:**

```
python3 standalone.py install 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
```

**I also ran setup.py, How can I make this project work?**

Comment: Sure but putting ‘silent! py3 pass’ in your vimrc is a better workaround.
Source: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/3062

Comment: or `brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim --with-python@2`

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев Why aren't you on Stack Overflow on Russian?

Comment: Where do I put that?  "brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim --with-python@2"